# refs/hoge/fuga など、標準的でない ref を表す名前はあるか

Tags: git

git において、 `git update-ref refs/hoge/fuga HEAD` などを行うと、`.git/refs/hoge/fuga` の ref を作成できます。

その際、 `git push REPO_NAME refs/hoge/fuga` などとすれば、そうやって作成した ref を push できることも確認しました。

このような標準的でない(heads, tags, remotes でない) ref を表す、総称的な名前はありますでしょうか。
資料を検索する目的などで、名前があるならば知りたいと考えています。
もしないのならば、一般的にどのような言葉で表現されるのかが知りたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

特別な名前は無いのではないでしょうか。一般的には refs (references) と呼ばれています。

gitrepository-layout(5) より

> ```
>    refs
>        References are stored in subdirectories of this directory. The git
>        prune command knows to preserve objects reachable from refs found
>        in this directory and its subdirectories. This directory is ignored
>        if $GIT_COMMON_DIR is set and "$GIT_COMMON_DIR/refs" will be used
>        instead.
> ```